# Regular experession to match math block

Tags: regex, typescript

Hi I need to match math block in string. The math block starts with $$ and ends with $$. There can be any number of math blocks.

for example input can look like:

```
abcd... asdfasdf
$$
math expression
$$
<another set of random words>
$$
expression
$$
...
```

What is the right regex to match only the math expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/sNmGqD/1)?

Comment: @Gurman It might be an issue that a single `$` is found within `$$`.

Comment: @TomFenech You are correct. I had just assumed there would be no `$` in the expression block.

Comment: @Gurman take a look at my answer below to see how you may match a single $ in the expression block in a regexp

Answer (score 1):

you could try `/\$\$((?:\$[^\$]|[^\$])+)\$\$/g` and that will match anything between $$ and $$ including single $.

Example:
http://regexr.com/3gu75

```js
let text = document.body.innerHTML;

let regex = /\$\$((?:\$[^\$]|[^\$])+)\$\$/g,
    match;

while( (match = regex.exec(text)) != null) {
   console.log(match[1].trim());
}
```

```html
abcd... asdfasdf
$$
math expression
$$
another set of random words
$$
expression
$$

$$
expression with a $ symbol
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is typescript, but i looked it up it's like javascript. Why don't you use new RegExp()? 
like new RegExp(/^\$\$.+\$\$$/g).exec(your str)
Char .+ will detect any character and so on until it find $ at the end. You can change this into your specific condition to match

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every odd-numbered `$$` starts a math mode block, and every even-numbered one ends the previous block, you could just split the string on `$$` and take the odd elements of the array:

```
> str=`abcd... asdfasdf
$$
math expression
$$
<another set of random words>
$$
expression
$$`
> str.split("$$").filter((s, index) => index % 2 === 1)
Array [ " math expression ", " expression " ]
```

The array still contains the leading and trailing spaces - you can use `String.trim` to get rid of them.

Comment: I think splitting is the most suitable option for me. Thanks.